# Is there a Linux command that writes its command line arguments to a file, without using a shell?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have a batch processing system that can execute a number of commands sequentially. These commands are specified as list of words, that are executed by python's `subprocess.call()` function, **without** using a shell. For various reasons I do not want to change the processing system.

I would like to write something to a file, so a subsequent command can use it. Unfortunately, all the ways I can think of to write something to the disk involve some sort of redirection, which is a shell concept.

**So is there a way to write a Linux command line that will take its argument and write it to a file, in a context where it is executed outside a shell?**

Comment: Are you doing this in the context of python, but don't want to run a subprocess with a shell?

Comment: @DanFarrell I don't want to modify the code that calls the commands, which is incidentally written in python.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. I recommend to completely rephrase this question and create a mcve.

Comment: @hek2mgl If you have specific unclear points I'd be happy to rephrase, but I'm not sure what to do here since I tried to be as clear as possible. I realize my use case is quite uncommon.

Comment: That's why I recommend rephrasing. I don't think you can improve the current question by changing it a bit. There is no code problem that can't be described with code.

Comment: I don't know how to rephrase it in order to make it clearer. I don't think adding code will help much.

Comment: I've put my actual question in bold. The rest is context, in case someone has a creative solution to offer.

Comment: What is a "linux command"? Do you have a list of linux commands? Is `sh -c "printf "%s" "$@" > file" --` a linux command? why? why not?

Comment: @KamilCuk any command that is part of the base install of any common linux distro. Anything from coreutils, sed, awk, etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk that's actually a great idea!

Comment: that's executed in a shell though

Comment: If you count `sh` with parameters as valid, which in itself is a shell script, why is it important that it is executed outside a shell? Which shell? If there's no shell, how are the parameters passed to the program? Does using a perl, awk, python or any other script language counts then? You can do the same with `python -c ....` and `perl ...` and so on...

Comment: @DanFarrell, the shell itself isn't.

Comment: My execution environment executes linux command lines outside of a shell. Think `execve()` and friends. But that doesn't mean I don't have a shell on my system.

Comment: Any sane execution environment of such kind would capture stdout and stderr from the command it executes. Unfortunately you didn't name that environment. Probably check the manual. If not, you can wrap the command specification in a shell: `ls -al /foo/bar` would turn into `bash -c 'ls -al /foo/bar/' > output`

Comment: How is this command supposed to know which file to write into? That's going to be one of the arguments, right? Or maybe via an environment variable? E.g. a program called`write-args` could work like this: `WRITE_TO=abc.txt write-args 1 2 3`, such that `1 2 3` gets written into `abc.txt`.  You could write `write-args` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one could write a generalised parser and process manager that could handle this for you, but, luckily, one already comes with Linux. All you have to do is tell it what command to run, and it will handle the redirection for you.

So, if you were to modify your commands a bit, you could easily do this.  Just concatenate the words together with strings, quoting when those words may have spaces or other special characters in them, and then you can use a list such as:

`/bin/sh`, `-c`, `{your new string here} > /some/file`

Et voila, stuff written to disk. :)

Comment: thanks, for some reason it never occurred to me to launch my own shell :)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the docs for [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), I see it has extra parameters:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

If you specify `stdout=` to a file you have opened, then the output of your code will go to that file, which is basically the same behaviour?

I don't see your exact usage case, but this is certainly a way to synthesise the command-line pipe behaviours, with little coding change.

Note that the docs also say that you should not use the built-in =PIPE support, depending on your exact requirements. It is important that you read data from a pipe regularly or the writer will stall when the buffer is full.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, I do not want to change the execution environment. I've edited the question to make it clearer in that respect.

Comment: Hmm... clearly you are going to make a mod somewhere. Adding an argument to your existing subprocess.call() seems to me like less work than building shell exec commands out of keywords, but your mileage may vary.